# Creating Heatmap in OpenLayers with Vector Source Containing LineStrings

Tags: openlayers, openlayers-3

I am interested in creating heatmaps in OpenLayers to visualize the density of certain observations in space. My data comes in the form of GeoJSON files, some of which contain point features, while others contain LineStrings.

I was able to create a vector source from the GeoJSON files containing points, successfully visualizing a heatmap layer from that source. However, I am unable to create a heatmap following the same procedure with the GeoJSON files contaning LineStrings.

Is this functionality supported at all?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Heatmap generates an image style which only works for point geometry.  For features with other geometry types the geometry of the style generated by the default style function could be changed to the label point of the feature geometry (for a LineString the mid-point of the line, or for a Polygon its interior point).  This is the OpenLayers example code, changed to use a GeoJSON consisting of LineStrings for a rail network.

```js
  var blur = document.getElementById('blur');
  var radius = document.getElementById('radius');

  proj4.defs('EPSG:4277', '+proj=longlat +ellps=airy +towgs84=446.448,-125.157,542.06,0.15,0.247,0.842,-20.489 +no_defs ');
  ol.proj.proj4.register(proj4);

  var vector = new ol.layer.Heatmap({
    source: new ol.source.Vector({
      //url: 'https://data.glasgow.gov.uk/dataset/d4b27465-b76c-4131-a1ff-31d038b8fdd0/resource/8eadfcc3-b91e-4b1a-a275-c0f1bcd8de7d/download/railway-line.geojson',
      url: 'https://mikenunn.net/data/railway-line.geojson',
      format: new ol.format.GeoJSON({
        dataProjection: 'EPSG:4277'
      })
    }),
    blur: parseInt(blur.value, 10),
    radius: parseInt(radius.value, 10)
  });

  var defaultStyleFunction = vector.getStyleFunction();
  vector.setStyle(function(feature, resolution) {
    var style = defaultStyleFunction(feature, resolution);
    var geom = feature.getGeometry();
    if (geom.getType() == 'LineString') {
      style[0].setGeometry(new ol.geom.Point(geom.getCoordinateAt(0.5)));
    }
    return style;
  });

  vector.getSource().on('addfeature', function(event) {
    var name = event.feature.get("IDENTIFIER");
    event.feature.set('weight', (name - 2500000000000)/200000000000);
  });

  var raster = new ol.layer.Tile({
    source: new ol.source.Stamen({
      layer: 'toner'
    })
  });

  var map = new ol.Map({
    layers: [raster, vector],
    target: 'map',
    view: new ol.View({
      center: ol.proj.transform([-4.23, 55.86], 'EPSG:4277', 'EPSG:3857'),
      zoom: 14,
    })
  });


  blur.addEventListener('input', function() {
    vector.setBlur(parseInt(blur.value, 10));
  });

  radius.addEventListener('input', function() {
    vector.setRadius(parseInt(radius.value, 10));
  });
```

```css
html, body, .map {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 90%;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.rawgit.com/openlayers/openlayers.github.io/master/en/v5.3.0/css/ol.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/openlayers/openlayers.github.io/master/en/v5.3.0/build/ol.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/proj4js/2.5.0/proj4.js"></script>
<div id="map" class="map"></div>
<form>
  <label>radius size</label>
  <input id="radius" type="range" min="1" max="50" step="1" value="25"/>
  <label>blur size</label>
  <input id="blur" type="range" min="1" max="50" step="1" value="15"/>
</form>
```